# Bootstrap typeahead using AJAX PHP and MySQL not showing data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-4, typeahead

I posted all images which are showing data backend but in front not showing data. My code is not working.

My code fetching data and showing data in console and browser network but not showing suggestion under text box like google what I have to check all the thing but not getting an idea

I don't understand this.

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
       <head>
         <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Autocomplete Textbox using Bootstrap Typehead with Ajax PHP</title>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />



     </head>
       <body>
     <br /><br />
      <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
      <h2 align="center">Autocomplete Textbox using Bootstrap Typeahead with Ajax PHP</h2>
    <br /><br />
    <label>Search Country</label>
    <input type="text"  name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Type Country Name" />
      </div>
    </body>
   </html>


            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#country').typeahead({
            source: function(query, result) {
                $.ajax({
               url: "autoselect_jquery2.php", // send request to a separate file         
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          query: query
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          result($.map(data, function(item) {

            return item;
          }));

              }
         })
               }
         });

        });
         </script>



            //autoselect_jquery2.php
         <?php
         //Assume this line is correct and that you have a database.php file containing your log in credientials
            include 'database.php';

        //If Statement says - run this next piece of code if $_POST['query'] is set to something 
            if (isset($_POST['query']))
     {

       // $search_query = $_POST['query']; - Commented OUT
      //This line attempts to sanatise the input from the posted data
      $search_query = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST["query"]);

            //This line constructs the whole SQL statement ( BAd methodology here, but thats a different topic)
            $query = "SELECT * FROM transporter WHERE email LIKE '%".$search_query."%' LIMIT 12";

         //You've commented out the next line and its of no use
          // $query = "SELECT * FROM transporter WHERE address LIKE  %' 

       //This line has a syntax error - but is also of no use - Should delete but should read  $search_query = ' LIMIT 12';
    //$search_query ' LIMIT 12";

       /// This line queries the database
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

       //This line declares $data will be an array
    $data = array();

       //If the DB returns some rows
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
       {
       // While there are results
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
       {
          //add to the $data array
           $data[] = $row["email"];
        }
          //Output $data in JSON format to be interpreted as a response from your ajax call
           echo json_encode($data);
     }
     }
       ?>
```

Comment: I'm using the same code whatever you mentioned and I've tried your code too. It's working fine. The problem might be your search data. Search available data from your Database

Comment: http://localdp.com/select_autosearch2.php

Comment: check this link but not working

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's not working as you are sending requests to the same file. Separate the files into two.

your html in `autoselect_jquery2.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Autocomplete Textbox using Bootstrap Typehead with Ajax PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  < br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
    <h2 align="center">Autocomplete Textbox using Bootstrap Typeahead with Ajax PHP</h2>
    <br /><br />
    <label>Search Country</label>
    <input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type Country Name" />
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#country').typeahead({
        source: function(query, result) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "search.php", // send request to a separate file
            method: "POST",
            data: {
              query: query
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
              result($.map(data, function(item) {
                return item;
              }));

            }
          })
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

create a new file `search.php`. change ajax url to point to `url: "search.php",`

```
<?php
//Assume this line is correct and that you have a database.php file containing your log in credientials
include 'database.php';

//If Statement says - run this next piece of code if $_POST['query'] is set to something 
if (isset($_POST['query'])) {

  // $search_query = $_POST['query']; - Commented OUT
  //This line attempts to sanatise the input from the posted data
  $search_query = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["query"]);

  //This line constructs the whole SQL statement ( BAd methodology here, but thats a different topic)
  $query = "SELECT * FROM transporter WHERE email LIKE '%" . $search_query . "%' LIMIT 12";

  //You've commented out the next line and its of no use
  // $query = "SELECT * FROM transporter WHERE address LIKE  %' 

  //This line has a syntax error - but is also of no use - Should delete but should read  $search_query = ' LIMIT 12';
  //$search_query ' LIMIT 12";

  /// This line queries the database
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

  //This line declares $data will be an array
  $data = array();

  //If the DB returns some rows
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // While there are results
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      //add to the $data array
      $data[] = $row["email"];
    }
    //Output $data in JSON format to be interpreted as a response from your ajax call
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
}
?>
```

[image: screen]

Comment: add console log in your success function `console.log(data);`

Comment: console.log(data); i have  posted and autoselect_jquery2.php i altered but no result found sir please help i am begginer i dont know how i complete my code please  help

Comment: http://www.localdp.com/select_autosearch2.php    sir you can check in inspect  response all the code

Comment: sir send ur email

Comment: check above code // autoselect_jquery2.php  php code please tell help me

Comment: this is full code shttp://www.localdp.com/select_autosearch2.php and autoselect_jquery2.php i have nothing else

Comment: i edit my question html and callng file in select_autosearch2.php and  in autoselect_jquery2.php has php code but not working sir check in console both file

Comment: I don't see the changes, please share the full code here codeshare.io/an7Erv  I can't see the php code in the browser.

Comment: and you are still using `url: "autoselect_jquery2.php"`, I told you to remove it and create a new file `search.php` and use `url: "search.php"`

Comment: select_autosearch2.php

Comment: do you have two files?

Comment: take a screenshot of your php file.

Comment: Sir my data base file has HTML code that is why not running now I clear HTML code from database file . It was showing in response  thanks everybody fro my help thanks a lot

Comment: please don't forget to accept my answer, by clicking the right arrow next to my answer.